# Hiding Classes/Methods From XML Documentation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, xml-documentation

I have a number of interfaces in an assembly which I need to document using XML-Doc and Sandcastle. However, there are also a few interfaces I would like to ignore when building the documentation file. Right now I manage to do it by compiling the assembly with those interfaces marked as `internal`, but this is more a workaround than a solution to the problem since, in fact, those need to be `public`. Is there some kind of attribute one can decoracte unwanted ones with so that they are ignored?

Comment: Are you looking to hide them from the intellisense, your Sandcastle generated documentation, or both?

Comment: Both, if possible! If not, only from Sandcastle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way to hide specific types/members from IntelliSense is to set their access modifier as you mention you currently do.

As far as doing this with Sandcastle, you can use API filters similar to what is discussed in [this MSDN blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sandcastle/filtering-apis-using-sandcastle).