# Omit specific properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio, documentation

In Visual Studio, is there a way to decorate specific properties to exclude them from the default xml documentation that a C# project generates?

Take the following example:

```
/// <summary>
/// This enables the external interface
/// </summary>
public string EnableExternalInferface { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// This should not be publicly visible
/// </summary>
public bool SecretFeatureSwitch { get; set; }
```

The ideal way would be to decorate it with some attribute.

After additional research I found the following question, [Hiding Classes/Methods From XML Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8772654/299327). It would be nice if this had move forward in the past year, but I am not hopeful.

Comment: First, why would you want to omit XML documentation of a public method/property? Second, why not just use a regular comment instead of XML comments?

Comment: @JustinNiessner for reasons that I can't really get into, this is how the database configuration works so many of these need to be public as in accessible, but not public as in viewable by the customer/support/etc. The regular non-xml comment would be an option to consider, but one downside would be the lack of intellisense for the property when in code.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a property say

```
public string val { get; set; }
```

With the XML Documentation enabled, you should see the following warning

"*Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member*"

Right click on the  warning in the error list and select show error help. It shows a webpage with information on "Compiler Warning (level 4) CS **1591**"

Use the warning number obtained above along with the C# Preprocessor Directive [#pragma warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys%28VS.80%29.aspx) around the property you want to omit from the documentation as shown below.

```
#pragma warning disable 1591
public string val { get; set; }
#pragma warning restore 1591
```

Comment: This is a good point, but I still may want some documentation for the property.